# Using jQuery to replace text inside H3 header

Tags: jquery, string, dom, text, replace

I tried to keep the code as simple/clean as possible. There is an h3 inside of two DIVs. The top DIV has an ID, the inner DIV a unique class.

```
$("#Events .event-header h3").html("your new header");
```

I also tried:

```
$("#Events .event-header h3").text("your new header");
```

Neither work. When I try them in the Chrome console, it tells me that the element I'm referencing is undefined and it doesn't know what text to target. The DIV structure couldn't be more simple and clear. I don't know how else to reference the h3 tag.

Any tips? (I've fixed the typo in the .event-header class - Apparently, posting comments instead of doing that previously is a grave sin. Happy Halloween?)

Comment: what's the return of $("#Events .events-header h3").size() ?

Comment: Do you have the h3 tag already in your HTML..

Comment: post your html and it will be a lot easier to find the solution

Comment: Hola,

The console displays:
TypeError: Cannot call method 'size' of null
arguments: Array[2]
get message: function () { [native code] }
get stack: function () { [native code] }
set message: function () { [native code] }
set stack: function () { [native code] }
type: "non_object_property_call"
__proto__: Error

Comment: It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/Kh7dw/ The problem is elsewhere

Comment: Are you calling this in DOM ready handler??

Comment: For those asking for HTML:

 <div id="Events" class="module upcoming-events">
    <div class="event-header">
        <h3>Upcoming Events</h3>
        <div class="pager">
            <a class="button-prev disabled">Prev</a>
            <a class="button-next">Next</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="c-events">
        <div class="c-events-content">
            <div class="not-found">No upcoming events scheduled.</div>
           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: I keep trying this on JsFiddle and it works. Put it on the site... Chrome says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'text' of null."

Comment: The error is with his class name. I updated a fiddle with his HTML structure http://jsfiddle.net/Kh7dw/1/. Problem was with his selector.

Comment: @user1729506 You see the edit-button below your question? Well, use it, instead of posting comments…

Comment: I will post comments if I choose. Thank you.

Comment: Editing the question is better than posting comments because new visitors will have the latest to work with instead of reading all the comments. Help us help you. Don't have to be rude about it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your class is `.event-header` not `.events-header`

There is an extra "s" at events.

So try this

```
$("#Events .event-header h3").text("your new header");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kh7dw/1/)

Comment: I've actually been sticking with $("#Events h3").text("your new header"); - which works on JsFiddle, but not my site. Double-checking my live code, the class reference is ok. I just messed up here. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Well even with your new selector it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/Kh7dw/2/ Like I said before, the error is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have conflict in your sites jquery using $ sign? Why dont you try wrapping it with this ready statement instead

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $("#Events .events-header h3").text("your new header");​
});
```