# Run JavaScript on every click within AJAX success function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I make three links on AJAX success function. I want a JavaScript function to run every time any of those links are clicked while user is on that page. I understand it is easy but I am unable to get the script run on every click. It just runs on clicking of first link and does nothing on clicking of other links. Here is the code:

```
request.success(function(data) {

            //Put the heading on the div
            //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898475/using-jquery-to-replace-text-inside-h3-header 
            var dataReceived = null;
            $("#bookList h3 #spanId").text("A list appears");

            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){

                dataReceived =data[i].name;
                $("#bookList").append("<a href id=bookLink>"+dataReceived+"</a>" +"<br>");
            }

            $("#bookLink").click(function(event){
                $.getScript("information.js",function(){                    
                    dealWithData();
                });
            });                 
        });

request.fail(function(jqXHR, status, errorMessage) {
            if((errorMessage = $.trim(errorMessage)) === "") {
                alert("An unspecified error occurred.  Check the server error log for details.");
            }
            else {
                alert("An error occurred:  " + errorMessage);
            }
        });
```

dealWithData for now just has an alert:

```
function dealWithData(){
        alert("Reached here");      
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Stop using duplicate IDs. They must be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: From the looks of it, it seems like you're adding multiple a tags all with id="bookLink"
id must be unique and it's probably hitting the first one that matches this id only, and failing to hit the others, causing your problem

$("#bookList").append("<a href class=bookLink>"+dataReceived+"</a>" +"<br>");

and $(".bookLink").click(function(event){

should take care of that

Answer (score 1):

I don't like using .click() any more since it has been deprecated.  You should also change it to use:

```
.on("click", function(event) {
```